# Return all elements by default with xsl:when test?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to make a web page that allows user inputs to search an xml file. There are multiple inputs, but I am having trouble accommodating empty inputs when the search is submitted.

```
var date = rDateSearch.value;   
if (date === "") {          
  var datein = "date=*";
} 
else {
  var datein = "date=" + date";
}
```

the 'date' variable is then sent to an `xsl:when` test. I want the `xsl:when` to return all date values.

Is there a way to do this? My current ideas aren't working.

This is a sample of my xml:

```
<record>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <date>1972</date>
    <rating>0.5</rating>
</record>
```

and this is my xsl. I'm unsure of the suitability of this code.

```
<xsl:for-each select="records/record">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test ="name=*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="date=*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test ="rating=*">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the XSL, to show what the context is when your `xsl:choose` is being applied. Also helpful to know what the XML looks like. Without knowing anything about how you are applying this, what about an expression that returns `true()` when there is no value for `date`, so that everything passes the @test criteria for your `xsl:when`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added samples as requested.

Comment: So, are you dynamically constructing your XSLT, substituting what is being assigned to the variable `datein` where you currently have `xsl:when test="date=*"`?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has not specified a value to filter the name, date, or rating, and you are trying to figure out what expression would select any/all, you could either use:

```
xsl:when test="date"
```

which will "pass" the test, as long as there is a `date` element in the `record` element being evaluated in the `xsl:for-each`.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
xsl:when test="true()"
```

which would evaluate as true, whether or not there is a date element.

The same logic applies for the other elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help!